# Xmi from iteraplan to visualparadigm

Tags: xmi, visual-paradigm, enterprise-architecture

EAM Tools typically have a repository plus reporting and visualisation on top.

Modelling tools are rather graphical and have a model underneath.

To use the best of two worlds I wanted to export the model from iteraPlan and use it for visualisations in VisualParadigm.

Sadly iteraPlan exports xmi 2.0 which can't be imported by my version of VisualParadigm.

Are there any known workarounds? E.g. convertors for different xmi versions?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you send your XMI to Visual Paradigm's support team (https://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/) and I'm sure they can help you out.